# Effect of Current on spring

Tags: electric-current

When Current passes thru a spring , some books mention that it gets compressed.
However, I think due to the heating effect of current, molecules will increase kinetic energy and the spring should get elongated. What is the physical mechanism for the compression instead of elongation?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampère's_force_law

Comment: I found d answer ... Its like this

There exists Heating Effect .. but its olmost neglible 2 d compression wic h takes place

Consider a spring .. which actli is like circular loop of many turns
Since , current will flow in same direction , even Directn of magnetic field too will be same
Thus .. Dipole will b created on each loop n dey will attract each oder

Comment: @user You are encouraged to answer your own questions for the benefit of future visitors and so that other user can vote on the answer that you have found.

Answer (score 1):

The current in the wire creates a magnetic field.  The magnetic field from each loop puts a force on the other wire loops that makes them compress together.

Comment: Put your right thumb parallel to the current in a segment of wire in one of the loops.  The magnetic field wraps around the wire just just like your fingers wrap around it.  That is Ampere's Law.  That field crosses other loops at right angles and causes a force F = I X B.  That is Lorentz' Law.

Comment: Yeah. Wires carrying current in the same direction are attracted towards each other.

Answer (score 0):

A probable solution may be:
There exists a heating Effect, but it's almost negligible to the compression Effect. 
Consider a spring which actually is like circular loop of many turns. Since current will flow in the same direction, even direction of magnetic field too will be the same. Thus dipole will be created on each loop, and they will attract each other.